# How to access session data in IAuthorizationHandler in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-authorization

I'm having difficulty accessing session data in a custom authorization handler, while it works elsewhere.

Session works properly in controller actions, but when I try to access it with `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session` in a `MyAuthorizationHandler.HandleRequirementAsync`, I get a `InvalidOperationException` "Session has not been configured for this application or request.".
The `IHttpContextAccessor` has access to query, cookies etc - but fails to access session data.

If I try to access the same `MyAuthorizationHandler`'s `IHttpContextAccessor` from a controller, session data is available.

`MyAuthorizationHandler` is injected as a singleton in `ConfigureServices`, full order of initialization:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); 
    services.AddSession(); 
    services.AddDefaultIdentity...
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddControllers...
    services.AddAuthentication...
    services.AddAuthorization...
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); 
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MyAuthorizationHandler>(); 
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>...
    services.AddMvc(o => o.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
}

public void Configure(...)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseEndpoints...
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Note: I cannot use claims in this handler, I need session data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The order of  `app.UseSession();` is incorrect , you should put it before any middleware which uses  the session.

```
public void Configure(...)
{
   app.UseSession();

   app.UseRouting();
   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseAuthorization();

   app.UseEndpoints...
   app.UseMvc();
}
```